# M2V and BIK to MKV

Tags: video-conversion

How do I remux bik files to mkv? I tried using ffmpeg and Shutter Encoder but neither of them worked. How do I convert them to mkv and other formats without losing quality?

I used ffmpeg -i input.bk -c copy output for ffmpeg and the rewrap function for Shutter Encoder but they didn't work.

Comment: We do not allow requests for software products here, so that part of your question will get this post closed. Rather, edit your post and tell us WHAT, PRECISELY you tried in ffmpeg and Shutter Encoder, and HOW these failed, and we may be able to help you figure out how to use these tools to more successfully meet your specific needs.

Comment: Bink video of RAD Game Tools is a proprietary format. I very much doubt you could put it in any other container.